# Does the container instance need to have a outbound https rule and either route table with IG or NAT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

For a EC2 instance to register with a AWS ECS Cluster does it need to belong to a security group with a outbound rule on at least HTTPS and be able to connect outside the vpc? (also having the ecsinstancerole AIM role)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an EC2 instance to be managed by ECS, the ECS Agent on the instance must be able to talk to the ECS service endpoints.  This means that either it needs to be in a VPC with internet access (via either an [internet gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) or [NAT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat.html), with appropriate security group outbound rules) or be configured to use an HTTP proxy.